# RecyclerView with disabled scrolling is not efficient

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I need an efficient RecyclerView with following features:

- nested in a scrollview, to scroll with other views
- fills all (estimated) space required to render all items
- render only visible items and reuse previously visible views.

Currently I can achieve feature 1 & 2 with disabling scrolling through LayoutManager:

```
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()) {
    @Override
    public boolean canScrollVertically() {
        return false;
    }
};
linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
TasksListView().setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
```

But in this case, all items will be rendered at beginning time. Obviously this is performance issue.

How can I say to RecyclerView just reserve estimated space for all items (using count of all items) and render items using previously created ViewHolders?

Comment: u want to a space between your data ?

Comment: I have same requirements. Did you get any solution? Please let me know how u achieved this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
import android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.view.View;


public abstract class RecyclerViewByNestedScrollListener implements NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener {
    // The current offset index of data you have loaded
    private int currentPage = 0;
    // The total number of items in the dataset after the last load
    private int previousTotalItemCount = 0;
    // True if we are still waiting for the last set of data to load.
    private boolean loading = true;
    // Sets the starting page index
    private int startingPageIndex = 0;
    // The minimum amount of pixels to have below your current scroll position
    // before loading more.
    private int visibleThresholdDistance = 500;

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    public RecyclerViewByNestedScrollListener(RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager) {
        this.mLayoutManager = layoutManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView scrollView, int x, int y, int oldx, int oldy) {
        // We take the last son in the scrollview
        View view = scrollView.getChildAt(scrollView.getChildCount() - 1);
        int distanceToEnd = (view.getBottom() - (scrollView.getHeight() + scrollView.getScrollY()));

        int totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
        // If the total item count is zero and the previous isn't, assume the
        // list is invalidated and should be reset back to initial state
        if (totalItemCount < previousTotalItemCount) {
            this.currentPage = this.startingPageIndex;
            this.previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
            if (totalItemCount == 0) {
                this.loading = true;
            }
        }

        // If it’s still loading, we check to see if the dataset count has
        // changed, if so we conclude it has finished loading and update the current page
        // number and total item count.
        if (loading && (totalItemCount > previousTotalItemCount)) {
            loading = false;
            previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
        }

        // If it isn’t currently loading, we check to see if we have breached
        // the visibleThreshold and need to reload more data.
        // If we do need to reload some more data, we execute onLoadMore to fetch the data.
        // threshold should reflect how many total columns there are too
        if (!loading && distanceToEnd <= visibleThresholdDistance) {
            currentPage++;
            onLoadMore(currentPage, totalItemCount);
            loading = true;
        }
    }

    // Defines the process for actually loading more data based on page
    public abstract void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount);

}
```

and then use NestedScrollView as parent of your recyclerView. Then in code do like this:

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this);

NestedScrollView mScrNested=(NestedScrollView)findViewById(R.id.nestedScrollView);

mScrNested.setOnScrollChangeListener(new RecyclerViewByNestedScrollListener(layoutManager) {
                @Override
                public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount) {
                    //load next page of your recyclerView
                }
            });
```

As you see at above, you must set load more of your recyclerview with nestedScorllView. Otherwise your data load at once and your view has lagged.
All of this problem is because recyclerView not work properly inside ScrollView.

Comment: I used the code, but while only 5 item will be displayed, all other (more than 30 items) will be rendered.

Comment: This method work with visible pixel (500px) of your screen at the end of nestedScrollView. How many data fetch at each page of your request?

Comment: I have 40 records for sample, only 4 item (and a little of 5th item) will be shown. My screen's height is  1920, nearly 1300 pixel by recyclerview, meaning each item takes approximately 400 pixels, so if item 6 and 7 will be rendered, code works correctly, but all items at the end will be rendered (~12.000 pixels)

Comment: Are you use setNestedScrollingEnabled(false); for your RecyclerView and android:fillViewport="true" for your NestedScrollView?

Comment: Yes, both are set, and renders all items regardless of visibility

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164911/discussion-between-masoud-mokhtari-and-homayoun-behzadian).